# Bigcommerce Faceted Product Filtering - Display Filter on Home Page?

Tags: filter, bigcommerce, faceted-search

We are a Bigcommerce Enterprise Customer. We are attempting to implement Faceted Product Filtering.

We have the filter working wonderfully but we would like the filter on the home page of the store.  Our developer is telling us that it can only be displayed on our category, brand and search pages. I am unsure if this is because they have elected to use a premium theme (Indiana) and are unable to regress the code (rather than use the build-up approach using the 'blueprint' theme as recommended in the filter SDK).

We intend to have users portal from our static site (on wix) to our store so want them to land on our store's home page and have the filter present and available for use on that page's sidebar.  As it is the user must select a category in and go down a level into the store before they are able to access the filter functionality.

I'm not a developer but if someone could give me a 'you need to investigate this or that' .. or 'it's because you are attempting to modify a complex theme,' I will at least know where I stand and be able to point the developer we have engaged in the right direction.   Of course, if it's just not possible, I would like to know this as well.

Thanks in advance, for any assistance or pointers to resources.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on Bigcommerce (their out of the box filtering) is crafted to work on the category, search, and brand pages as your developer mentioned. You can have some sort of filter experience that is custom built and doesn't rely on the Bigcommerce created filtering to help facilitate a customer experience such as a year/make/model filter you might see on cart part stores.

Comment: Thanks Alyss,  I guess that means that it is NOT possible if we are sticking with the BC implementation of Faceted Product Filtering.  Our developer has implemented a filter that litereally forms the entire sidebar. We wanted this to be the landing page. As it is, it is kind of wedged under an unsightly 'category' widget.  Is it possible to hide this category widget then?

Comment: is it not possible to show filter box on the landing page with basic bigcommerce. Filterbox is present in the category page but not working if I copy that code to the home page.

Comment: Do I need any addon to do this?